# Access SELECT Me.HWND

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm working in an MS Access Database, and have the following query:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO My_Table_Temp (Value1, Value2, IsDirty, HWND)" _
& " SELECT Value1, Value2, 0 as IsDirty, " & sqe(Me.HWND) & " as HWND" _
& " FROM My_Table; "
```

The idea is that I load values from the database into a temporary table, which I can then bind to a control, so I can add and remove values from it, before writing the values back into the database.

My problem is that HWND never gets set, so that when I filter by it to save the records, nothing gets picked up. The values already in the database show up, it's just the HWND that never gets set. Am I missing something completely obvious?

Comment: Have you confirmed `sqe(Me.HWND)` returns the value you expect?  Out of curiosity, what is that value?

Comment: Just MessageBoxed it, It returns a Window handle, a numeric string.

Comment: I understood window handle.  What does your `sqe()` function do?

Comment: Sorry, it returns an escaped string from whatever you pass into it.

Comment: I suspect we may need to see the text of the `INSERT` statement you're asking the db engine to execute.  Store it in a string: `strSQL = "INSERT INTO My_Table_Temp ….` and `Debug.Print` the string.  Then you can execute the string: `CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailonerror`  Make sure `SetWarnings` is `True`

Comment: Where will I see the Debug output?

Comment: In the Immediate window.  You can use `Ctrl + g` to go there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173927/discussion-between-joshua-moore-and-hansup).

Comment: `Form.Hwnd` is a Long Int, there is nothing to escape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a msaccess MDB, and then created a "hr_training_levels_temp" table.
I do not have the "FROM" table, 
so I hard-coded some values (and changed values suffixing with '2')... as in this sql --

```
INSERT INTO hr_training_levels_temp
            (traininglevel,
             trainingleveldesc,
             traininglevelid,
             trainingid,
             isdirty,
             hwnd)
SELECT 'lvla', 
       'lvla-desc', 
       'lvla-id',  
       'tr-id',  
       0        AS IsDirty,
       '920902' AS HWND
```

And in msaccess, when I double-click on the table I got this result --

```
traininglevel   trainingleveldesc   traininglevelid trainingid  isdirty HWND
lvla            lvla-desc           lvla-id         tr-id       0       920902
lvla2           lvla2-desc          lvla2-id        tr-id2      0       920903
```

Do you see such a result in the msaccess table itself?

Then when your display screen comes back and does a select using HWND, is it the same HWND that was used to do the Insert?

Comment: Hi @donPablo, I see all the results except for the hwnd.

Comment: In my temp table HWND is int, what is the type for HWND in your table? string or int or ???  Then, when you open the table do you see zero, blank, ??? Can you cut/paste sample rows?  Can you debug.print Me.HWND to see its value? and debug.print sqe(Me.HWND)

Comment: Just another thought -- the INSERT happens only when the WHERE is true.  So lets look at the WHERE for a moment...   WHERE TrainingID=2 AND TrainingLevelID NOT IN (SELECT TrainingLevelID FROM HR_Training_Levels_Temp WHERE TrainingID=2)   ... ... What are these values? and is there a chance that the Insert never happens?